# Can you override Material UI effects while using Chart Js?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, chart.js

I am currently trying to make a card component that contains a chart. I created this line chart with Chart Js and my React JS is primarily in MUI, when I wrap a Paper or Card component around the chart it changes some of the styles, for example making the background white. If I have it in a div it keeps its properties, does anyone how to go about and fix this?

```
  const labels = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];

  const data = {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Assessment Score",
        data: [20, 50, 40, 80, 100],
        fill: false,
        borderColor: "#a259ff",
        tension: 0.1,
        fill: true,
      },
    ],
  };
  const options = {
    scales: {
      x: {
        grid: {
          color: "#3c3c3c",
        },
        ticks: {
          color: "#ffffff",
        },
      },
      y: {
        grid: {
          color: "#3c3c3c",
        },
        ticks: {
          color: "#ffffff",
        },
      },
    },
  };
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        background: "linear-gradient(180deg, #1a1a1a 10%, #4b4b4b 75%)",
        color: "#1b1b1b",
        height: "100vh",
        width: "100%",
      }}
    >
      <Paper sx={{ w: "250px", h: "400px" }}>
        <Line data={data} options={options} />
      </Paper>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ApplicationContent;
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to define the chart stylings otherwise parent styling override the chart in some cases. below code worked for me -

```
<div
  style={{
    background: "linear-gradient(180deg, #1a1a1a 10%, #4b4b4b 75%)",
    color: "#1b1b1b",
    height: "200px",
    width: "100%",
  }}
>
  <Paper sx={{ w: 250, h: 400, background: 'red' }}>
      <canvas style={{ background: 'white' }} id="chart-id" />
  </Paper>
</div>
```

here you can see I have defined my chart background. In your code I can see a component **Line**. Guessing it is a wrapper around the main chart. you need to add the stylings to the element which has the id/ref for chart. you can pass style/className as props to **Line** component and then assign those to the chart element. Let me know if this answer helps.